# Passing a variable in a get query Play

Tags: javascript, java, playframework

I'm using Play Framework and I have a variable called "id". I have defined a function that looks like this:

```
setInterval(function() {
$.get("file2", function(id){
   $("#result").html(id);
    })
}, 5000);
```

What I want to do is to obtain what I plot in file2.html and pass the variable id to this file, as it needs it. The controller looks like this:

```
public static void file2(Long id) {
        //Some operations with the required variable id
        render(variable);// Render the result
    }
```

When I try to compile it, it tells me that id is undefined. It is defined in file1.html, but apparently the way I'm passing it to file2.html is not correct and I can't perform the operations needed by the controller as it needs the id that I'm passing wrong.

Any ideas on how to do it right? PS: I've checked that id is available in file1.html, and yes it is.

PS2: This is the error code:

Execution exception

*`IllegalArgumentException occured : id to load is required for loading`*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to pass the id as part of the URL.

Also, I'd recommend putting this in a function that can call itself again in the callback, using setTimeout, so that it waits till you get a response before allowing another call.  This stops things getting messy in the case where it takes longer than 5 seconds to make the call.

Try this...

```
// main function for calling your server-side method
function file2(id) {
    $.get("file2?id=" + id, function(data) {
        $("#result").html(data);
        setTimeout(function() {
            file2(id);
        }, 5000);
    });
}

// run it once after 5 seconds and then in will run itself after that
setTimeout(function() {
    file2(id);
}, 5000);
```

Comment: The route it tries to access then is http://localhost:9000/project/file2?{%20id:%20%27151%27%20}, and not just http://localhost:9000/project/file2?id=151, where 151 is the id. How can I solve this?

Comment: It doesn't need the ajax call in that case.  I was treating it like a web service - I'm not familiar with Java backends.  I'll amend it to suit.

Comment: That should now solve your immediate problem, but one thing that I have to ask is, are you changing the value of `id` or will it always be the same?

Comment: It remains the same as it corresponds to a simulation id, fixed for this html file 1. Thanks!